# Adding fling gesture to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, gestures

I'm trying to add fling gesture to an imageview. Im using this code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private void onCreate() {
    final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}               

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Right to left
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Left to right
        }

        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Bottom to top
        }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Top to bottom
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

But it just doesn't work. The log says nullpointerexception and it refers to this line  `imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {`

Where is my mistake? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your imageView returning null because U haven't setContentView() before actually getting the imageview

`setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` in your onCreate before getting the imageview

Comment: thanks :D
the thing is that i added this code before the setcontentview so i just moved it to the top and now it works :)